# How can i loop this code in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

im making a friend adder for teenspot and this is what i have. basically you click a button and it adds the person selected on the list, then you have to click it again to add the next one. the thing is i need to know how to loops this so it just keeps moving down the list adding people automatically

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.teenspot.com/profiles/" & ListBox.SelectedItem & "/add")
    ListBox.SelectedIndex = ListBox.SelectedIndex + 2
    ' This is the "sleep" function.
    ' This makes your webbrowser finish loading before new action.

    Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete And WebBrowser1.IsBusy = False
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop


    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("confirm").InvokeMember("click")
```

ive tried multiple times with do...loop and for..next and all that kinda stuff, but i still havent figured it out. what it does is, it only runs through the add me pages and never clicks confirm which is the second part. im kinda new to vb so if someone can i help id really appreciate it

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused.  Are you clicking on a button, and then adding a person to listbox?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this:

> the thing is i need to know how to loops this so it just keeps moving down the list adding people automatically

To add all friends in the list with one button click:
Use **For Each/ Next**

```
For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.teenspot.com/profiles/" & item & "/add") 
    Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = Complete And WebBrowser1.IsBusy=False        
       Application.DoEvents()    
    Loop    
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("confirm").InvokeMember("click")
Next
```

To add only the selected friend and then move the selected listitem one step down to wait for a new button click, do this:

```
If Not ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.teenspot.com/profiles/" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "/add") 
    If Not ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
    Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = Complete And WebBrowser1.IsBusy=False        
       Application.DoEvents()    
    Loop    
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("confirm").InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

And for this:

> it only runs through the add me pages and never clicks confirm which is the second part.

We have to know how the HTML-document is made up to research this, has the element "confirm" a javascript-click-event or is it just a post-form-button? I cant check this out without be logged in to the site. (And Im not a teenager so I will not create an account there) ;-)

But, you should be able to perform the click without InvokeMember I think. Like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("confirm").click()
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think I've done it like that before.
If the button has a javascript like click="AddFriend()" or something like that, maybe you could use the invokescript to call that function directly instead of clicking the button, like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("AddFriend()")
```